# Create new Parse.Session programmatically for a user, without their password

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm working on a existing Parse server, and I am currently adding an OAuth system, so that external apps can connect in the name of Parse.User.

I created different classes for codes and tokens, and now my external apps can send requests with an accessToken, corresponding to their application and user (who granted access).

I'm looking for a way to inform the Parse server that the "logged in user" in requests is the end user that authorized the OAuth application. For this, I have created an express middleware handling request before the Parse server middleware, extracting the access token from the request, getting the correct User and Application, and then I wanted to create a Parse.Session programmatically, get the token, and set it in the request as `x-parse-session-token`. This way, the next handler, Parse, would treat the request as authenticated and performed by the end user.

My problem here is that I cannot find a way to create a session programmatically, I'm aware of the Parse.User.logIn, but that works only with a password.

I've tried the following:

```js
const oAuthSession = await new Parse.Session().save({
  user: user // user got from Parse.Query(Parse.User) with masterKey
}, { useMasterKey: true })
```

But get a `Cannot modify readonly attribute user` error.

Any hidden method to programmatically create a Parse.Session without a password ?

Comment: Just answered you in community forum. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @DaviMacêdo, answer in the forum is working great. If you post it here I will accept it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @DaviMacêdo in the community forum: https://community.parseplatform.org/t/create-new-parse-session-programmatically-for-a-user-without-their-password/1751

We can inject the user directly in the request field, and it will be picked up by Parse: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/f6a41729a7a3adc6bd5310cefb3458835b4abb58/src/middlewares.js#L199

```
const user = await new Parse.Query(Parse.User).get(‘idOfUser’);
req.userFromJWT = user;
```